# flutter create new account button does not work

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

```
2021-07-29 18:38:36.528495+0300 Runner[7225:3339676] flutter: selected Languageenglish
2021-07-29 18:38:36.534379+0300 Runner[7225:3339676] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] 
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      _CreateNewAccountState.callRegisterAPI.<anonymous closure> 
(package:mealup/screens/auth/create_new_account.dart:543:49)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
#3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:172:20)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:719:47)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:740:24)
#6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:550:5)
#7      _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:274:13)
#8      _RestClient.register (package:mealup/network_api/api_client.g.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

i am trying to run the app on ios device and this is the output i get.

Comment: can you add some code snippet of that?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with null safety.

`Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`

You probably used the ! syntax on a null value. Therefore, your function crashes and no action has been done when you tap on the button.

Checkout the [null-safety documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)